# Proof or exceptions of this guaranteed differentiability of function

Tags: derivatives, continuity

My teacher stated a theorem without proof:-

> If g(x) is continuous at x=a, f(x) is differentiable at x=a and f(a)=0 then f(x)•g(x) is differentiable at x=a

First of all I wanted to know a proof of this theorem (I hope it exists) if it is easy to understand using simpler terminologies. Well, most probably I think I would not be able to understand it.
Anyways my real question is that " Is this statement always valid without any exceptions?". Talking about this chapter specifically I have came around a lot of statements which seem always true at first sight, but after a long research, it turns out that few rare exceptions exists. My faith gets shaken. That is why I wanted to be sure before blindly believing it and commiting a mistake in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a true statement. Since $g$ is continuous at $a$, it is bounded near $a$; what this means is that there is some $M>0$ and some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $|x-a|<\varepsilon\implies\bigl|g(x)\bigr|<M$.

So,\begin{align}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)}{x-a}&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{x-a}\\&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}g(x)\\&=0,\end{align}since $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{x-a}=0$ and $g$ is bounded near $a$.